# Receive SMS broadcasts in Android 6.0+

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am attempting to create an SMS app. Currently I am having a problem receiving SMS broadcasts. I have set my app as the default SMS app. When I receive an SMS, I would expect for the log message "received intent" to be printed, but nothing happens. What am I missing?

Below is my `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
package com.idioticdev.android.converse;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;

public class ConverseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        android.util.Log.d ("Converse", "recieved intent");
    }
}
```

And my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.idioticdev.android.converse"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <receiver android:name="ConverseReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="ConverseReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="ConverseService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name="Converse"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Converse"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you handling the permissions correctly for the API level you're running under? Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission).

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you, that was the problem. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind, I'll vote it as a duplicate of that post, and you should be able to mark it as helpful to close out your question. Cheers!

Comment: you may not handling the permissions correctly for the API level you're running under